# select K-elements from an array of size N, such that the difference between the minimum and maximum element in the sub-array is least

Tags: xcode, algorithm, arrays

How to select K-elements from an array such that the difference between the minimum and maximum element in the subarray is least

Example: Given Array

```
     100 200 20 10 30 32 35 50 60 28 18
     k=4
```

Various possible Outcomes

```
    10 18 20 28
    max-min = 28-10 = 18

    28 30 32 35
    max-min = 35-28 = 7
```

etc.

```
  So, we will select [28 30 32 35] as the subarray
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let the array be a[1..N]. Sort it. Then pick the subarray a[i], a[i + 1], ..., a[i + K - 1] , i = 1, ..., N - K + 1, such that a[i + K - 1] - a[i] is minimal. You can do this in linear time. Since the sorting takes `O(nlogn)` the total execution time of the algorithm is `O(nlogn)`